# Git - Cannot delete remote branch

Tags: git, git-remote, git-tag, git-branch

I made a git branch unintentionally named "0.2" which is also a tag.

So I tried to remove it from origin:

```
$ git branch -rD origin/0.2
Deleted remote branch origin/0.2
```

But then:

```
$ git fetch origin
 * [new branch]      0.2        -> origin/0.2
```

Here is the error I got wwhen pushing:

```
$ git push --force origin :0.2
error: dst refspec 0.2 matches more than one.
```

So I removed the remote tag:

```
$ git tag -d 0.2
$ git push origin :refs/tags/0.2
```

Still no go:

```
$ git branch -rD origin/0.2
 * [new branch]      0.2        -> origin/0.2
```

1. Is it a git bug?
2. Did I do something wrong apart from having a tag and branch name equals?
3. How to remove this remote branch?

Comment: Have you tried `git push origin :0.2`?

Comment: does the remote tag still exist? also try `git remote prune origin`

Comment: `git branch -rD origin/0.2` is the same as `git push origin :0.2` for newest git version. And yes the remote tag was still there. I also tried the `prune`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally running `git push --force origin :0.2` after having deleted (locally and remotely) the tag should do the correct deletion.

Comment: Indeed, doing my two commands together solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
$ git push --delete origin refs/heads/0.2
```